# Using NF with FPAT – what am I doing wrong?

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv, gawk

When NF is used with FPAT regex, the comma is considered a field. I prefer using NF and FPAT:

1) NF – to limit the output to the actual number of fields for the record

2) FPAT – to handle an embedded comma in a quoted field like line 3:

```
 "Bus Driver, City/Transit",51
```

3) the awk script is used for several input files that have a different number of columns for record 6 - record 6 is the column name/header for the contents of the file...

The output from testing, the first, test1, uses a fixed value for number of fields, the second, test2, uses NF for the number of fields.

using gawk 4.1.4

```
    BEGIN {
            FPAT = "(^,)|([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
            OFS = "\t"
        }

    NR == 6 {

       for (i = 1; 6 >= i; ++i) {
       #for (i = 1; NF >= i; ++i) {

           colName[i] = $i
           print "Column Name: " colName[i]

    }    

      { print "", "number of fields: " NF }
    }
```

Input File starting at record 6: NR == 6 {...

```
    Occupation,States Licensed 
    Barber,51 
    "Bus Driver, City/Transit",51
```

The output I expect/want:

```
    Column Name: Occupation
    Column Name: States Licensed
        number of fields: 2
```

test 1:  for (i = 1; 6 >= i; ++i) {...

output is correct - what I expect/want, except, of course, for the 4 columns/fields that are not valid but are shown because of using a fixed value of 6.

```
    Column Name: Occupation
    Column Name: States Licensed
    Column Name: 
    Column Name: 
    Column Name: 
    Column Name: 
        number of fields: 2
```

test 2:  for (i = 1; NF >= i; ++i) {...

output is NOT what I expect/want; note the comma is a indicate as a field

```
    Column Name: Occupation
    Column Name: ,
    Column Name: States Licensed
        number of fields: 3
```

Comment: The problem is your regex I think - try `FPAT = "\"[^\"]*\"|[^\",]*"` (a possibly empty sequence of non-quotes surrounded by quotes, or a possibly empty sequence of not-comma-or-quotes). Or more readably `gawk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^",]*' '<stuff>'`

Answer (score 3):

## 0. Congratulations.  You seem to have found a bug in gawk.

I’ve reduced this to a very small example. 
(It might be possible to demonstrate the glitch
with a simpler `FPAT` string,
but I didn’t feel like spending another ten minutes on that.) 
Basically, for input like `foo,bar`, we can get two different results.

**Case A:**

```
NF = 2
$1 = foo
$2 = bar
$3 =
```

and

**Case B:**

```
NF = 3
$1 = foo
$2 = ,
$3 = bar
```

This code produces **Case B:**

```
BEGIN {
        FPAT = "^,|[^,]+"
}

{
        print "NF =", NF
        print "$1 =", $1; print "$2 =", $2; print "$3 =", $3
}
```

(I removed the parentheses from `FPAT`, because they aren’t needed;
I removed the part of the regular expression that handles
quoted strings maybe containing comma(s),
and I cut the code down to a bare minimum.)

Use

```
echo foo,bar | awk -f name_of_the_above_awk_script
```

But — in gawk version 4.1.1, at least —
if I access `$1` before we access `NF`, then I get **Case A.** 
You can demonstrate this by switching the order of the `print` statements,
or by this ridiculous kluge:

```
{
        temp = $1                       # We will never use this.
        print "NF =", NF
        print "$1 =", $1; print "$2 =", $2; print "$3 =", $3
}
```

This is clearly a bug; there’s no way that *accessing* a field
should change the values of other things.

## 1. So we have a work-around.

Just add `temp = $1` before your `for` loop,
and I expect you’ll get the result you want (using `NF`).

## 2. The real (?) answer:

In the above, I deliberately avoided referring to either Case A or Case B
as “right” or “wrong”. 
Case A is the one you want,
but Case B might actually be the *correct* result
for the value of `FPAT` that you’re using. 
It seems to be saying that you want a field to be

- a string beginning with a comma, or
- a string of one or more characters that aren’t comma, or
- a quote, a string of one or more characters that aren’t quote,
  and another quote.

But you don’t want a comma to be a field;
you just want the second and third options. 
I find that setting

```
FPAT = "[^,]+|\"[^\"]+\""
```

will give you the correct results.

Comment: Interesting and such a simple solution. The regex I used  was copied from the GNU AWK website/page, "The GNU Awk User’s Guide": 
[GNU.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content)
except that I added the **(^,)|** at the start for some now unknown reason (doh!?). Thank you for your time, detailed solution and well laid-out presentation - much appreciated and I learned something. I wonder if I should let GNU.org know about the error in the manual, re: the parenthesis in the regex. Would it be OK if I quote your solution?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I didn't have to add **temp = $1**. It works fine without it.

Comment: (1) The inclusion of the parentheses in `FPAT` is (as far as I can tell) unnecessary, but it’s harmless; I wouldn’t call it an error.  Adding the `(^,)|` at the start ***was the error**.*  But, yes, you may quote me if you say my name and link to the answer. (2) Adding ``temp = $1`` was a kludgy workaround to get the program to produce the desired results even with the wrong `FPAT`.  So you don’t need to use the kludgy workaround *and also* fix `FPAT`.  Sorry I wasn’t clearer about that.

Comment: using `gawk 4.2.1` under Debian Testing, i got case B with our without `temp=$1`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Thanks for checking that. I observed the bug in version 4.1.1.

Comment: @TomM While you don't (yet) have enough reputation to upvote helpful answers, I suggest you *accept* this answer (click on the check mark next to it). It's highly unlikely that you'll get a better one.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers  BTW, I was the one who upvoted your question because it was such a good one. Welcome to [unix.se]!